# Hadoop commands run manually also run with shell script in ubuntu but if I run that script using Crontab then it will not Work

Tags: hadoop, cron, hdfs

I found following error while execute Crontab.

> "/home/sqoop/proddata/test.sh: 2: /home/sqoop/proddata/test.sh: hdfs: not found"

I run the following command in the terminal, and also the same command I mention in Script and both are working but using cron it does not work

```
# hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hadoop/table/testtable

# vim test.sh
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hadoop/table/testtable
```